# Postgres sequence usage

Tags: postgresql, schema, permissions, sequence

I have an Postgres database with two users: `dev` and `junit`. Junit and dev objects are dropped and created regularly.

They both have the same objects unshared for tables, however, sequences are shared, and `dev` is the owner. I just use normal `create` statements.

I want to `grant all` to `junit` for the sequence but this fails with:

```
dev=> grant all on sequence serial to junit;
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "serial"
GRANT
```

After this `junit` has no select rights on the sequence, how can I fix this?

I also would like to know whether there are recipes for this kind of setups, where I can use the same DDL for the two different users without modifying the script? I've been looking into schemas but I haven't found the solution so far.

Comment: We generally prefer to have two individual questions for the two decisively distinct questions you presented. The second part shouldn't be here. You can always link to a previous question for context.

Answer (score 4):

The warning

> ```
> WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "serial"
> ```

indicates that the granting role **doesn't have the necessary privilege** to grant privileges on the object in question.

- Either execute the `GRANT` command as the role *owning* the sequence.
- Or do the same as superuser (default superuser is `postgres`).
- Or `GRANT` the necessary privilege to the role `dev` so that this role can in turn grant it to others:

```
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE serial TO dev WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The **name** `serial` for a sequence isn't particularly wise, but since `serial` is not a name of a base type and [not a reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), it wouldn't cause any immediate trouble.

Aside:
Unfortunately the manual uses the name `serial` in the [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html) and [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html) examples. I feel like a suggestion to pgsql-docs@postgresql.org might be in order ...

Answer (score 3):

`SERIAL` is an alias datatype for an `INTEGER` type column with a defult coming from a sequence. If you defined your table as having a `SERIAL` type column, then you need to get the actual name of the sequence from the table.

Have a look at the output of `\d your_table` and retry your `GRANT` command with the proper sequence name. If you *did* name your sequence "serial" (which would be unwise), then you should double-quote "serial" in your `GRANT` command.

Regarding your other question, you can collect the object definitions into one (or more) file.  Create a schema for `dev` and another for `junit`, and then create the objects with an other script like

```
SET ROLE TO dev;
SET search_path TO dev;

\i object_definitions.sql

SET ROLE TO junit;
SET search_path TO junit;

\i object_definitions.sql

RESET ROLE;
```

Comment: @dezso, you could have created a new answer to garner the points for yourself (I will +1 if you do). Either way, thank you for properly finishing my answer, that was good of you.

Comment: I would just repeat yours anyway, this is more economical :)